# create rectangles in java netbeans with data from database mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, rectangles

I want to create rectangles in java netbeans-7 with data From my mysql database as a Gantt chart, but I do not know how to do

Comment: Write a little code to show what do you want.

Comment: try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mosaic","root","");
            rs=st.executeQuery("Select from,to,couleur from test");
        System.out.println(""+rs);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(""+rs.getInt("from"));
         g.setColor(color.green);

Comment: Sorry, I can't read your code. Format it.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a library called [jFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) which can do this for you however if you want to do it yourself then you'll have to read the [Java Tutorials on Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and, since you already know how to get the data from the database, that should be enough with some trial and error.